# IAP subscription

Tags: subscription, in-app-purchase

I'm developing a specialist app which generates digital output (a spreadsheet) depending on a set of input parameters. The app is growing and based on the fact that Apple won't charge for app-upgrades, I've been using IAP purchases to allow access to new features. OK, this works to an extent but I am in danger of annoying customers due to number of IAP purchases that now need to be made.

So I'm looking at the subscription model for the app which will allow users to pay a rolling subscription to access various parts of the app...possibly a database or access to the cloud.

Simple question....and I can't quite fathom this out from their guidelines....is it allowed? Are you allowed to say have a subscription IAP model for access to the cloud, or access to features.

Any advice appreciated

/Confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html